# How to draw offcanvas of offscreen canvas to onscreen canvas?

Tags: javascript, canvas, 2d

## What

I'm making a 2D game on pure JS and I use CanvasRenderingContext2D.translate() to emulate camera movements. I mean that my drawable level is much bigger than the canvas itself (when the canvas size for example is about 1920x1080, player can stand at (72000, 72000) coordinate).

Everything works well, but now I'm trying to implement shadows and lights using offscreen canvas that I fill with black and make arc areas with calculated alpha where the lights sources are positioned on the level.

## Problem

When I try to copy offscreen canvas to onscreen one, it's always rendered at (0, 0) of onscreen canvas with the canvas size (1920x1080 from example).

## Some code if you need it

That's how I setup the canvas created on html page

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas1");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

canvas.width = document.body.offsetWidth;
canvas.height = document.body.offsetHeight - 50;
```

That's how I create offscreen canvas in code

```js
// canvasSize is a real size of onscreen canvas, nothing changes if I set it to 72000x72000
var offScreenCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
offScreenCanvas.width = this.canvasSize.x;
offScreenCanvas.height = this.canvasSize.y;
var context = offScreenCanvas.getContext("2d");
```

That's some ways I tried to draw it

```js
// where c is onscreen canvas context
c.putImageData(context.getImageData(this.camera.pos.x, this.camera.pos.y, this.canvasSize.x, this.canvasSize.y), this.camera.pos.x, this.camera.pos.y);
```

```js
c.drawImage(offScreenCanvas, 0, 0);
```

```js
c.drawImage(offScreenCanvas, 0, 0, 72000, 72000);
// also tried other overloads
```

All of these ways are ended up with the same result